# how to manage viewing of top components in java swing

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZJyq.png)

I want to switch between top components taps using code without need to click the tab
I have three top components, two of them are "editor" top component
an the third is explorer top component
when I do some thing in the third i want to control which of the two "editor" be viewed (selected)
I'm using Netbeans Platform.

Comment: The components are in JTabbedPane?

Comment: Please share some code. Whats Taps?

Answer (score 1):

For JTabbedPane you can switch tabs by calling `setSeldctedTab()`

See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedComponent(java.awt.Component))

Comment: thank you Jan , but here I have two top components viewed as taps , there is no JTapedPane used

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the selected element in your "explorer" component you could use a `CardLayout` to switch the view (to the correct editor).

See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details